# How do I make specific words turn different colours?

Tags: html, css, styling

I am wondering how to make different words turn different colours in my webpage. EG: "This" would turn red, but "box" would turn blue.

So far I have this:

```
    <div class="scroll">
          <p class="margin">This box should scroll when it runs out of space.This box should                    scroll when it      runs out of space.This box should scroll when it runs                   out of space.This box should scroll when it runs        out of                  space.This box should scroll when it runs out of space.This box should scroll                   when it runs out        of space.This box should scroll when it runs                    out of space.This box should scroll when it runs out of                 space.This box should scroll when it runs out of space.This box should scroll                   when it runs out of         space.This box should scroll when it runs out                   of space.This box should scroll when it runs out of         space.This box                  should scroll when it runs out of space.This box should scroll when it runs out                 of      space.This box should scroll when it runs out of space.This box                 should scroll when it runs out of       space.This box should scroll                    when it runs out of space.This box should scroll when it runs out of                    space.This box should scroll when it runs out of space.This box should scroll                   when it runs out of         space.This box should scroll when it runs out                   of space.This box should scroll when it runs out of         space.This box                  should scroll when it runs out of space.This box should scroll when it runs out                 of      space.This box should scroll when it runs out of space.This box                 should scroll when it runs out of       space.This box should scroll                    when it runs out of space.This box should scroll when it runs out of                    space.This box should scroll when it runs out of space.This box should scroll                   when it runs out of         space.This box should scroll when it runs out                   of space.This box should scroll when it runs out of         space.This box                  should scroll when it runs out of space.This box should scroll when it runs out                 of      space.This box should scroll when it runs out of space.This box                 should scroll when it runs out of       space.This box should scroll                    when it runs out of space.This box should scroll when it runs out of                    space.This box should scroll when it runs out of space.This box should scroll                   when it runs out of         space.This box should scroll when it runs out                   of space.This box should scroll when it runs out of         space.This box                  should scroll when it runs out of space.This box should scroll when it runs out                 of      space.This box should scroll when it runs out of space.This box                 should scroll when it runs out of       space.This box should scroll                    when it runs out of space.This box should scroll when it runs out of                    space.This box should scroll when it runs out of space.This box should scroll                   when it runs out of         space.This box should scroll when it runs out                   of space.This box should scroll when it runs out of         space.This box                  should scroll when it runs out of space.This box should scroll when it runs out                 of      space.This box should scroll when it runs out of space.This box                 should scroll when it runs out of       space.This box should scroll                    when it runs out of space.This box should scroll when it runs out of                    space.This box should scroll when it runs out of space.This box should scroll                   when it runs out of         space.This box should scroll when it runs out                   of space.
        </p>
    </div>
```

Edit:

Um, sorry. I don't really understand what any of you are saying, or how to use them.

Comment: Do you want the color to be random? Or do you want each word to have it's own color?

Comment: I want it to have its own color

Answer (score 2):

[Nic Meiring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1091688/nic-meiring) answered a valid solution but it is difficult to change color in long paragraphs by finding specific words and applying css on them. It is OK in case of short texts but for long paragraphs and variable texts, you need to apply a general solution.

CSS solution: *(Not sure about all browsers)*

- [Overriding The Default Text Selection Color With CSS](http://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/)

If you are allowed to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

- [highlight: JavaScript text higlighting jQuery plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)

or You can use string replacing methods in a server side language. For Example [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) in PHP:

```
$text = str_replace("red", "<span class='red-class'>red<span>", "This is red");
```

Comment: agreed 100% with @NAVEED that this is a more sustainable solution. Was just trying to stay within the html, css, styling tags :)

Answer (score 1):

you could create span around the words you want to change the color of.

I created a demo for you at http://jsfiddle.net/LwR8D/

Comment: better to use `class` in the CSS and not `id` in this case (hundreds of "This" on the page)

Comment: agreed. would be better ot use class if you wanted, for example, every instance of "This" on the page to be the same color

Comment: Thanks. This has helped me very much.

Comment: But, I just noticed, It only makes one line go coloured. How do I make all the words get coloured.

Comment: see @NAVEED answer below for changing all of them quickly

Answer (score 0):

Dirty-but-working solution with innerHTML:

```
var words_and_colors = [
    {'word':'this', 'color':'red'},
    {'word':'to', 'color':'blue'}
];

function hilte_words_in_element (element, words) {
    for (var z=0; z < words.length; z++) {
        var re = new RegExp('('+words[z]['word']+'\\b)', 'gi')
        element.innerHTML =  element.innerHTML.replace(
            re,
            "<span style=\"color:"+words[z]['color']+"\">$1</span>"
        );
    }
}
hilte_words_in_element(document.getElementById('changeMe'), words_and_colors);
```

Fiddle with it: http://jsfiddle.net/8vDgH/

Note that this is considered "bad" -- one should not deal with `innerHTML` if it can be avoided. Not knowing the circumstances that you're using it in, I can't make a more specific interaction with DOM; you DO know what you're using it for, so I suggest you refactor the code to use a more acceptable means of altering node content.

Also note that if this can be accomplished on the server-side, it would be much more efficient. You would use a similar concept, but do so before the content has been output. I do not know if this is viable for your use-case, but if so, there is no question it would be the route with best performance (and you can avoid the dreaded and evil `innerHTML`)

Comment: How do I make every word a different colour? Not just "This"

Comment: The upper array stores a list of words to be color changed and the corresponding color. The example shows the words "to" and "this" being changed.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I know question hasn't any `javascript` or `jquery` tag, but this could be a suggest :)

append this to @Nic Meiring answer:

add following line into your `<header></header>` section of page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then add another `<script></script>` section for calling following javascript in your pages 
`<header></header>` section:

```
(function($) {
  var thePage = $("body");
  thePage.html(thePage.html().replace(/This/ig,'<span id="This">This</span>'));
})(jQuery)
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/LwR8D/4/)

[Use jQuery to Replace a Word](http://bavotasan.com/2010/jquery-replace-word-with-link/)

Comment: Um, I've never seen any code like that, what type of code is it?

Comment: jQuery (which is javascript) - it is just a self-calling function; a bit of code wrapped in a closure that is called immediately after it is created.

Comment: sorry, i don't get what you mean?

Comment: Also, i dont just want it to be "This" that is getting changed. I want every word to be changed.

Comment: Well, IMO this is a bad solution anyway (Adding jQuery for one thing, seriously?! Fanboys, gah!)

Comment: add following line into your `<header></header>` section of page: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`